# Select one entry from another Select

Tags: php, mysql, rank, userid

Hey i'm trying to get the rank from a specified player id.

I use phpMyAdmin MySQL InnoDB and PHP.

I two have databases.

Userdatabase has one table called users.
The table has 5 fields: id, username, email, password, and date.

The second database is called scores and have one table for each level.
All tables has the same fields: id, score, time, bonus, timestamp.

I connect to the scores database right away like this:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $mysql_db);
```

.

```
$multisql .= "SET @rank := 0;";
$multisql .= "SELECT *, @rank := @rank + 1 AS rank FROM $table AS s
LEFT JOIN userdatabase.users AS u ON s.id = u.id
ORDER BY score DESC, timestamp ASC LIMIT 10;";
```

This query returns all entries with the correct rank but i only want the one with id $userid, so i try:

```
$multisql .= "SET @rank := 0;";
$multisql .= "SELECT *, @rank := @rank + 1 AS rank FROM $table AS s
LEFT JOIN userdatabase.users AS u ON s.id = u.id
WHERE u.id = $userid
ORDER BY score DESC, timestamp ASC LIMIT 10;";
```

This returns only the specified users result, but the rank is always 1.

I try to wrap the Select in another Select like this, but I don't get a result doing it like that.

```
$multisql .= "SET @rank := 0;";
$multisql .= "SELECT * FROM (
SELECT *, @rank := @rank + 1 AS rank FROM $table AS s
LEFT JOIN userdatabase.users AS u ON s.id = u.id
ORDER BY score DESC, timestamp ASC
) rank WHERE id = $userid;";
```

I have tried a few different variations of the above example but nothing works. I'm quite sure it should be possible to have two SELECT after another. I tried following the answer from this [post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/73168/score-ranking-no-tie-if-tie-order-by-score-submit-date) which is close to what i'm after.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: you are doing `SET @rank := 0;` and then you are doing `@rank := @rank + 1` what did you expect?

Comment: When i do `SET @rank := 0;` and `@rank := @rank +1` it works just fine in the first example I get the correct rank from each entry.

Comment: The final example works for me ( albeit a little edited to suit db )

Comment: It is the same as what they did in the post i refered to at the end. [post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/73168/score-ranking-no-tie-if-tie-order-by-score-submit-date)

Comment: Sorry my bad, misinterpreted your query

Comment: No problem $Naruto, maybe the problem isn't the query, but how i handle the result. I do it like this, but as you can see, i never reach a serten point.

`if (mysqli_multi_query($conn, $multisql))
{
  do
  {
  echo "This runs";
    if ($result = mysqli_store_result($conn))
    {
      echo "This never runs...";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running an experiment, using different tables and columns but effectively using your final query appears to yield the results you are looking for.

Firstly the base query to show all records and all defined columns in a test table

```
mysql>select * from `customers`;
+----+---------------------+-------------------+
| id | cust_name           | cust_address      |
+----+---------------------+-------------------+
|  0 | Charlie Farnsbarnse | Alpha Centauri    |
|  1 | Joe Bloggs          | Nowhere Important |
|  2 | Fred SMith          | Somewhere else    |
|  3 | Barney Gumble       | Brooklyn          |
|  4 | Betty Boop          | Hollywood         |
+----+---------------------+-------------------+
```

Then, after setting up the variables run a new query to show the rank for each.

```
mysql>set @id=4;
set @rank := 0;
select *, @rank := @rank + 1 as 'rank' from `customers`;

+----+---------------------+-------------------+------+
| id | cust_name           | cust_address      | rank |
+----+---------------------+-------------------+------+
|  0 | Charlie Farnsbarnse | Alpha Centauri    |    1 |
|  1 | Joe Bloggs          | Nowhere Important |    2 |
|  2 | Fred SMith          | Somewhere else    |    3 |
|  3 | Barney Gumble       | Brooklyn          |    4 |
|  4 | Betty Boop          | Hollywood         |    5 |
+----+---------------------+-------------------+------+
```

Finally with the additional restraint imposed by the where clause return only a single record with the rank as seen in previous query.

```
mysql>set @rank := 0;
select * from (
    select *, @rank := @rank + 1 as 'rank' from `customers` as s
) rank where id = @id;


+----+------------+--------------+------+
| id | cust_name  | cust_address | rank |
+----+------------+--------------+------+
|  4 | Betty Boop | Hollywood    |    5 |
+----+------------+--------------+------+
```

This was run from the command line but I see no reason why using the PHP variable `$userid` should fail when substituted into your sql.